# Use the Amazon Alexa Skill CLI to update the Interaction Model

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-echo

Trying to update the interaction model of my skill using the command line based AWS CLI.  Until now I've been copying the interaction model directly into the online skill editor.  What's the best process for doing this programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Update your Alexa Skill Interaction Model Via the AWS CLI:

1) Setup an AWS CLI Profile using credentials from your AWS IAM Profile
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

```
$ aws configure --profile [PREFERED PROFILE NAME]
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7_EXAMPLE_FOUND_IN_IAM
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCY_EXAMPLE_KEY
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]: json
```

In the Command Line:

```
SKILL_ID=[YOUR SKILL ID FOUND AT DEVELOPER.AMAZON.COM]
CLI_PROFILE=[YOUR CLI PROFILE CREATED ABOVE]

ask api update-model -s ${SKILL_ID} -p ${CLI_PROFILE} -l en-US -f [PATH TO FILE]/InteractionModel.json
```

Note:

- en-US updates the english interaction model

Return Data:

```
Model for en-US submitted.
Please use the following command to track the model build status:

ask api get-skill-status -s amzn1.ask.skill.4245ff2e-476c-418b-8004-dc63346dc432e4
```

To Track your progress be sure to append your AWS_CLI profile

```
ask api get-skill-status -s amzn1.ask.skill.4245ff2e-476c-418b-8004-dc63346dc432e4 -p ${CLI_PROFILE}
```

Tracking Result Data:

```
{
  "interactionModel": {
    "en-US": {
      "eTag": "f05823449ac35d318acb4096d061eaa8",
      "lastUpdateRequest": {
        "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
      }
    }
  },
  "manifest": {
    "eTag": "df3b0a7c544b5c0ee006e34cf726dcd2",
    "lastUpdateRequest": {
      "status": "SUCCEEDED"
    }
  }
}
```

`LastUpdateRequest` `Status:` Should Eventually Read `SUCCEEDED`

Forewarning:

- You cannot update the Invocation Name of a live skill.  This is the only error I've run across so far. `"message": "InvalidStageInvocationNameChange: You cannot change the invocation name for a live skill."`

Answer (score 0):

I don't use this, but you probably want the "ASK CLI":

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html